# How would you express 'drained of' in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, verbs

I'm trying to translate the phrase 'drained of' in Latin, for example in the sentence 'I have been drained of all my energy'. All of the words for draining which I have found work more in the sense of 'all of my energy has been drained from me', with the thing which is being drained as the object of the verb. Is there a construction for 'to drain someone of something' with 'someone' being the direct object of the verb?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but does *exuo* work in the right order for you? what examples did not work?. in [L&S dictioanry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=exuo) many examples are to be found with the accusative as the direct object that from him something (in the ablative) is taken. like *hostem armis*

Comment: I think 'exuo' could work, thank you. I was thinking originally of words like 'exhaurio' and 'perhaurio'.

Comment: yes. I think there are better fits than *exuo* as I sense *to drain* has some little different nuances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you describe a state of exhaustion, you can of course use *exhaurire*:

> Omnes vires meae exhaustae sunt.

Perhaps a dative of disadvantage might also sound good, i.e. *omnes vires mihi exhaustae sunt*; depending on context, an abl. abs. would also be possible (e.g. *omnibus viribus exhaustis languidus noctem exegi* etc).

Another possibility would be *privare* or *spoliare*, where the latter also exists in the (perhaps more attractive) forms *despoliare* and *exspoliare*; e.g.

> omni vi (vel omnibus viribus) corporis animique exspoliatus sum

These also satisfy your wish for a construction where the affected person is the direct object of the verb.

Comment: Is 'omnibus viribus' dative or ablative in your example with 'exspoliare'?

Comment: @outisnemo Ablative.